# error: ERROR: SSL error: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661)

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose

We are building docker environment.  When we are trying to run the below command "docker-compose up",  we are getting below error.

**ERROR:**

> SSL error: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661)

we have tried following command in docker shell and restarted docker service

export COMPOSE_TLS_VERSION=TLSv1_2

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO club ) Please show value of `COMPOSE_TLS_VERSION` env variable. E.g. `echo $COMPOSE_TLS_VERSION`

Comment: Can you post your YAML?